# More info about the use of "bezüglich"

Tags: verb

Can somebody try to explain in short,  when it is appropriate to use bezüglich and when it is not?

Comment: Regarding your question... Did you try to answer the question yourself before asking?

Comment: Do you have any examples on how you think you would use it or not?

Comment: Why "in short" - either you are interested in an answer and getting smarter or not..

Comment: In short, because I though that it could be more complex matter. 
Yes, I have tried to answer the question. 
Example of use: Can I talk with you about your mother? I want to join the cause, if it is about a fair cause. Is this question of money or is it about something else?

Comment: Per OP's comment on an answer, I narrowed the question by asking what "bezüglich appears to be an abbreviation for," and wonder if the question can be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu i think the edit you performed is not a good edit. I don't see any reason for editing the question to talk about an abbreviation. The 'in short' previously i  that question has nothing to do with the length of the word, but is a request to keep anwers short and understandable. For these reasons I rolled back. If you disagree, I suggest you chime in on [chat] and Ping me. I'll be lurking around there the whole day tomorrow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"bezüglich" is normally not used in colloquial language. It is cumbersome written language,
meaning concerning. It is often used when it is a bit difficult to find an appropriate preposition. A variant for "bezüglich" is "in Bezug auf". In English concerning.

Answer (score 0):

As you like it short:

> Using `bezüglich` is appropriate, if you want to explicitely refer to something.